# HTML Title Attribute Instead of The Tag Content

Tags: accessibility, html, css

Considering accessibility, can I use:

```
<a href="about.html" title="About"></a>
```

without any content, instead of:

```
<a href="about.html">About</a>
```

Associated with this CSS rule:

```
a[href="about.html"]:before {
    /* 1F6C8  CIRCLED INFORMATION SOURCE = information */
    content: "\1F6C8";
}
```

Supposing that an appropriate font is available. I actually use RichStyle font.

Comment: No. And since the site you're linking is yours and it's supposed to be about CSS you should know that without question.

Answer (score 2):

You could, but assistive technologies handling of title tags isn't perfect (more on [WCAG](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H33.html)).

A better solution is not to use a title tag and instead [hide the element text using css](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H33.html).

CSS:

```
a span { height: 1px; width: 1px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: -10px; }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#"> <span>Washington stimulates economic growth </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this.

In [my answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32854051/1591669) I outlined which cases of CSS content generation are possibly inaccessible/accessible, and your example is definitely inaccessible to several user groups, for example:

- Users of clients without CSS support (e.g., browsers with CSS disabled, text browsers, feed readers, printers, …) won’t be able to recognize/use this link.
- Users that use speech input to navigate your page will likely not be able to target this link directly.
- Users that use screen readers to access your page might not understand what this link is about (depends on screen reader capability/configuration).

Besides being problematic for accessibility, it can also be a usability problem:

- Users that don’t load your font (because they have JavaScript disabled, or their network filter doesn’t allow it, or they have disabled it for security reasons, etc.), and don’t have a font installed that contains a glyph for this Unicode icon, would just see a confusing box.
- Icon-only links (whether used in accessible or inaccessible ways) are rarely a good idea, as not all people will understand the icon or interpret it in the same as you, and it breaks searching (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) for this link on the page, and it breaks translation of this link, etc.